# Cannot get wireless to work after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless

My hard drive crashed that was running Win8 so I installed Ubuntu 12.4 on my HDD. I can connect to wired connection but no wireless. I have checked drivers and they seem good. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

```
damulag@damulag-Satellite-S55-A:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for damulag: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c2400000-c2403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 54:be:f7:49:db:2b
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=1.2.3 duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:c1000000-c103ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
damulag@damulag-Satellite-S55-A:~$ ifconfig eth0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
damulag@damulag-Satellite-S55-A:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c2400000-c2403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 10
       serial: 54:be:f7:49:db:2b
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx driverversion=1.2.3 duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:c1000000-c103ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
damulag@damulag-Satellite-S55-A:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

"UNCLAIMED" means there are no drivers attached to your card. Since there are no drivers attached to your card you wifi will not work.

Try this solution, it is marked as solved so it should work for you:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2162026

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I just did not want to seem like I was taking credit for the answer from someone else in another forum.

Comment: If that page disappears someday, your answer will be useless. There's no problem citing other sources since you provide the link. If you don't want to earn reputation from someone else's work, [edit] your answer and mark the "community wiki" box.